# How long can I hold onto a ContentResolver in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, screen-rotation

I'm trying to write an Activity that spawns off an AsyncTask for a long-running operation, and periodically publishes status updates back to the Activity. I'd like to make sure the AsyncTask survives screen rotation or other destruction conditions like OOM correctly.

[I've read this thread on the android-developers list](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e1d5b8f8a3142892), which in turn [led me to this implementation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java), which is almost what I need. However, the last step of my AsyncTask is to delete some data from a content resolver. It is extremely important that this step is not skipped, because the data is sensitive and should not be left on the phone under normal conditions. However, ContentResolvers come from Contexts, in this case the Activity, and with this scheme the Activity may be null by the time the AsyncTask is ready to do the deletion.

Is it safe to get a ContentResolver from the Activity at AsyncTask construction and hold onto that past the lifetime of the Activity? If not, what can I do to handle this case?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you get the ContentResolver from the Application ? You need to understand the different concepts behind an Activity and Context - just because an Activity is a Context, doesn't mean that you need to use an Activity for all tasks that it does. Use an Activity only for UI stuff

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dbe5f18d3dba9aa9/fa4b981f635f16db?lnk=gst&q=getbaseContext#fa4b981f635f16db is a mail from the same developer that says "Don't use getBaseContext(), just use the Context you have.". So I guess my question is, what contexts do I have? Is the Application context preferable to the Base context?

Comment: Yes the Application context is the preferable way, because it exists always (if your code is actually executing at the moment and needing a context, there is a live Application object). Create a static instance of your application. in it's onCreate: instance=this; and create a public static Application get()  { returns instance;}. That way you will always have a context when you need one